# Wurmcoil Engine vs. Oko, Thief of Crowns

Tags: magic-the-gathering

A [Wurmcoil Engine](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWurmcoil%20Engine%5d) becomes a 3/3 Elk creature due to [Oko, Thief of Crowns](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOko%2c%20Thief%20of%20Crowns%5d)’ second ability. Wurmcoil Engine is then sent to its owners graveyard. Does Wurmcoil Engine’s death ability trigger?

Answer (score 8):

No, the ability will not trigger.

“When dies” triggers count how the object existed immediately before it moved to the graveyard to see if there were any relevant abilities that triggered; and Wurmcoil did not have any abilities at that time.

> 603.10. Normally, objects that exist immediately after an event are checked to see if the event matched any trigger conditions, and continuous effects that exist at that time are used to determine what the trigger conditions are and what the objects involved in the event look like. **However, some triggered abilities are exceptions to this rule; the game “looks back in time” to determine if those abilities trigger, using the existence of those abilities and the appearance of objects immediately prior to the event.** The list of exceptions is as follows:
>
> > 603.10a Some zone-change triggers look back in time. These are **leaves-the-battlefield abilities**, abilities that trigger when a card leaves a graveyard, and abilities that trigger when an object that all players can see is put into a hand or library.